# Difference between real-time database and fireStore in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

As fireStore is the new inclusion as real-time database into firebase, obviously it will outperform the old real-time data ablaze in every aspect. What are the actual differences between the two databases ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why you should use firestore over realtime db:

- Shallow queries

  - Fetching a node does not fetch you all of the subnodes together
- Queries can be done on multiple fields

  - Realtime db only support querying on a single field
- Queries scale to size of result set, not size of data set

  - Search for top 10 will take same amount of time whether you have 300, 300 
    thousand or 30 million entries
- Manual fetching of data

  - One time fetch queries is the primary use case, listeners for realtime updates is configurable. See [Getting Realtime Updates with Cloud Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/listen)
- Multi region support

  - Redundant database (not sure about realtime db redundancy but it does have an auto backup price plan)
- Different pricing model

  - Price based on number of reads and writes, not amount of data downloaded (can be good or bad depends on usage, see below)

### Why you should use realtime db over firestore:

- Slightly better latency

  - Faster update on client than firestore
- Native support for presence

  - User online status is easier to be implemented on realtime db
- Pricing model

  - If your app does a lot of reads and writes with small data, realtime db can be cheaper than firestore
- Firestore is still beta

  - Realtime db has been in production for four years, firestore is just recently released

### TL;DR:

New apps should start with firestore.

Existing apps using realtime db should stay with realtime db. Unless you have a good enough reason to switch, you dont.

Source: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/10/cloud-firestore-for-rtdb-developers.html

Comment: I'm not sure blatant statements like "New apps should start with firestore" makes sense. They are built for slightly different use cases and should be treated as such